# Read from binary file where double and string were saved

Tags: c++, file, binary

I write in a binary file double and strings. I want to read this file but since data types are mixed how can I read the content of the file correctly? (Know when the line is a string or a double)

This is my code :

```cpp
int main(){



    double nb = 26.2254;
    std::string str = "Hello";



    std::ofstream myfile("test.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    myfile.write(str.c_str(), str.length());
    myfile.write((char*)&nbstr, sizeof(nb));
    myfile.write(str.c_str(), str.length());
    myfile.write(str.c_str(), str.length());

    myfile.close();


}
```

I made an alternative by converting `nb` to a string before writing it into the file so i can read only strings. I don't know if it's a good solution.

```cpp
int main(){



    double nb = 26.2254;
    std::string nbstr;
    std::string str = "Hello";
    std::ostringstream ss;

    nbstr = std::to_string(nb);


    std::ofstream myfile("test.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    myfile.write(str.c_str(), str.length());
    myfile.write(nbstr.c_str(), nbstr.length());
    myfile.write(str.c_str(), str.length());
    myfile.write(str.c_str(), str.length());

    myfile.close();

    std::ifstream openfile("test.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    ss << openfile.rdbuf();

    openfile.close();


    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: For strings, the usual way to go about it is to prepend the length before the actual data. If you don't know in which order you'll be getting data, you can prepend an identifier before each item and get it based on that

Comment: You can't treat a binary file like it contains text, which is ultimately what you do when you read it into the `ostringstream`. There's also the problem that unless the text you write is of a fixed length known beforehand, you need to save the actual length as well so you know how many characters to read. And generally, *don't* use binary files, text-files are often so much easier to handle for simple purposes.

Answer (score 0):

For binary file you somehow need to specify length of written string. It can be done either by explicitly writing length, i.e.

```
size_t len = str.length();
myfile.write(&len, sizeof(len));
myfile.write(str.c_str(), len);
```

or you can just write `'\0'` - terminate character, at end of string, which is helpfully provided by `c_str()`, so you just need to write it:

```
myfile.write(str.c_str(), str.length() + 1);
```

When reading, you are either reading length first, or searching for `'\0'` in file.

BTW, instead of using `write()` and `read()`, it would be easier to use `<<` and `>>` operators, like this:

```
myfile << str;
myfile << nb;
```